# How to invoke the Body Field of a custom Content Type from database for showing in a Block?

Tags: database

For my custom content type, I used .install file to install the custom fields and create my form same as following:

```
function inep_form($node, $form_state) {
    return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

And i added Body field and an Image field in my inep.install:

```
...
node_add_body_field($types['inep']);
$instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'inep');
$instance['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';
field_update_instance($instance);
...
```

And an Image field with:

```
...
'field_name' => 'image_upload',
...
```

And now I have an error for invoking the body and image field from database for showing in:

```
inep_block_view($delta='') {
    ...
    $result = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'body', 'image_upload'))
    ->condition('type', INEP_NODE_TYPE)
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->execute();
    ...
}
```

!PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: n.body...

It means they don't store in database?!

But i can edit my fields later...

And also tried "body['und'][0]['value']" But same error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The standard body field is added in other table named "field_data_body", Not in node table.